# Sleep calculator with decimal in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to calculate my time slept by using a formula with decimal numbers ?

For exemple :

If I go to bed at 23h55 I will write : 23.9

And I get up at 7h05 I will write : 7.1

How do I calculate the difference between them as time slept ?

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: How does `23:55` translate to `23.9`?

Comment: It would be easier to use a real datetime format and calculate the difference between those. Advantages being existing working code, capable of dealing with timezone and daylight saving changes. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-timedelta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has the handy `datetime` module to facilitate this sort of thing. You can express times as a `datetime` object and then simply calculate the difference between them:

```
import datetime

to_bed = datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=8, day=17, hour=23, minute=55)
got_up = datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=8, day=18, hour=7, minute=5)

time_slept = got_up - to_bed
print(time_slept)
```

Output: 7:10:00, indicating the interval between the two.